# can i use chromium for flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So i installed flutter(i use zorinOS). After following some steps, i run flutter doctor and get:

```
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
```

I don't have any chrome in my os.I use brave as my default browser, and i have deleted my firefox(my previous browser). I just wonder, do i need to install Chrome specifically? Can't i just install Chromium or use other browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't test our development flow with Chromium, so I'm not sure.

This requirement is only necessary for development: debugging, etc. We rely on Chrome features to enable our development experience.